# MySQL append one column below another

Tags: mysql, sql

Just wanna do this
[Append one column below another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908608/append-one-column-below-another)
in MySQL select

table:

```
id | x | y |
1  | a | b |
2  | c | d |
```

result i want to get:

```
id | x |
1  | a |
1  | b |
2  | c |
2  | d |
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `union all`.  If you care about the ordering:

```
select id, x
from ((select id, x, 1 as n from t) union all
      (select id, y, 2 as n from t)
     ) xy
order by id, n;
```

If you don't care about the ordering, then `union all` is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works for me